# moving pivot values to rows

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am using pivot tables to sum up columns in my table. Reason for not using SUM formula is because I'm using slicers and timeline to make the charts more interactive with filters (using pivot charts).

During creaton of the pivot table, columns (ie. column 1, column 2, column n) go into the ROWS field, and I would need to drag them one-by-one into the VALUES field.

I have tried recording macros, but the column headers may change, and the code would not work without specifying the exact name.

Is there a VBA code to automate this?

Comment: Is there any pattern to do so? How do you want VBA to do that if you don't tell it what you need? You want to put all your columns as values? Some of them?

Comment: Did you give my answer a try? If it works fine for you, please consider to mark it as answer as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). If not, don't hesitate to comment below it.

Answer (score 0):

The placement of a `PivotField` is defined by its `Orientation`.

You need two simple loops:

- add every row field as a value field
  and define its function, numberformat and so on
- remove the row fields

Example:

```
Private Sub PivotRowsToValues()
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim pf As PivotField

    For Each pt In ActiveSheet.PivotTables

        ' use each row field also as value field:
        For Each pf In pt.RowFields
            With pf
                .Orientation = xlDataField  ' xlColumnField
                .Function = xlSum           ' xlCount, ...
                .NumberFormat = "General"   ' "0.00", ...
            End With
        Next pf

        ' remove each row field
        For Each pf In pt.RowFields
            pf.Orientation = xlHidden
        Next pf

    Next pt
End Sub
```